# How to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_k^{k+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-st} dt $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I need to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_k^{k+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-st} dt $ but unfurtunately I have no Idea how to do that or how to start. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The integrals are immediate an the sum is geometric.

Comment: Try evaluating the integral, then summing, or take the sum inside the integral if you can, then evaluate, then integrate.

Comment: what a depressing qzestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_k^{k+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-st} dt
& =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{s}e^{-st} \bigg|_k^{k+\frac{1}{2}}
\\
&=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-ks}-e^{-(k+\frac12)s}\right) 
\\
&=\frac{1}{s}\left(1-e^{-\frac12s} +e^{-s}-e^{-\frac32s}  +e^{-2s}-e^{-\frac52s} +\cdots               \right) 
\\&=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^ne^{-\frac n2 s} 
\end{align*}$$

As Martin says above, the sum is geometric. 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^ne^{-\frac n2 s} &= \frac{1}{s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(-e^{-\frac s2 }\right)^n
\\
 &= \frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{1-\left(-e^{-\frac s2 }\right)} \quad\quad \text{for $e^{-\frac s2 }<1$}
\\
 &= \frac{1}{s\left(1+e^{-\frac s2 }\right)} \quad\quad \text{which is for $s>0$}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wrong sign: $\left(e^{-kt}-e^{-(k+\frac12)t}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you! The final result should be $\frac{1}{s(1+e^{\frac{-s}{2}})}$

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start with the change of variable $u = st$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- Using the substitution $u=-st$ and $\text{d}u=-s\space\text{d}t$:

$$\int e^{-st}\space\text{d}t=-\frac{e^{-st}}{s}+\text{C}$$

- $$\int_{k}^{k+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-st}\space\text{d}t=\left[-\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\right]_{t=k}^{k+\frac{1}{2}}=-\frac{1}{s}\left[e^{-st}\right]_{t=k}^{k+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{e^{-s\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(e^{\frac{s}{2}}-1\right)}{s}$$

So:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-st}\space\text{d}t=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(e^{\frac{s}{2}}-1\right)}{s}=$$
$$\frac{e^{\frac{s}{2}}-1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-s\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{e^{\frac{s}{2}}-1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\exp\left[-s\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]=$$
$$\frac{e^{\frac{s}{2}}-1}{s}\cdot\frac{\text{csch}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{2}=\frac{1}{s+se^{-\frac{s}{2}}}$$